# Filter pyspark DataFrame by string match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

i would like check substring match between comments and keyword column and find if anyone of the keywords present in that particular row.

**input**

```
   name               comments                keywords
0  paul      account is active  active,activated,activ
1  john   account is activated  active,activated,activ
2   max  account is activateds  active,activated,activ
```

**expected output**

```
match 
True
True
True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient here is to loop, you can use `set` intersection:

```
df['match'] = [set(c.split()).intersection(k.split(',')) > set()
               for c,k in zip(df['comments'], df['keywords'])]
```

Output:

```
   name               comments                keywords  match
0  paul      account is active  active,activated,activ   True
1  john   account is activated  active,activated,activ   True
2   max  account is activateds  active,activated,activ  False
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['paul' , 'john' , 'max'],
                   'comments': ['account is active' ,'account is activated','account is activateds'],
                   'keywords': ['active,activated,activ', 'active,activated,activ', 'active,activated,activ']})
```

With a minor variation you could check for substring match ("activ" would match "activateds"):

```
df['substring'] = [any(w in c for w in k.split(','))
                   for c,k in zip(df['comments'], df['keywords'])]
```

Output:

```
   name               comments                keywords  substring
0  paul      account is active  active,activated,activ       True
1  john   account is activated  active,activated,activ       True
2   max  account is activateds  active,activated,activ       True
```

Comment: @koushik great, then you might want to update the description and expected output in your question ;)

Comment: does the same method works in pyspark as well ? as my dataset is huge i tried to convert it to pandas but due to driver memory issue cant convert it to pandas

Comment: @koushik you might need different syntax for pyspark, I couldn't tell you as I don't use it. You should ask a separate question if needed ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
keys = ('|').join([f'({x})' for x in df['keywords'].iloc[0].split(',')])
df['comments'].str.contains(keys)
```

Output:

```
0    True
1    True
2    True
Name: comments, dtype: bool
```