# Filter pyspark DataFrame by partial string match

Tags: pyspark

would like check substring match between comments and keyword column and find if anyone of the keywords present in that particular row.

```
name  : ['paul','john','max','peter']
comments :['account is active','account is activated','account is activateds','account is activ']
keywords :[ 'active,activated,activ'  , 'active,activated,activ' ,'active,activated,activ','null']
```

expected output

```
match = ['True','True','True','True']
```

Comment: Can you post a code sample of what you have already tried?

Comment: key = list(df1.select('keywords').toPandas()['keywords']
pat = '|'.join(key)

output = df1.filter(col('comments').rlike(pat))

this one doesnt check the second value in the string if the first dont match it skips to next row

Comment: Any reason why instead of editing the question you posted it twice? [Filter pyspark DataFrame by string match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71822349/filter-pyspark-dataframe-by-string-match)